# Squash League Results - SQL Query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have recently taken over running the internal leagues at the squash club I play at

I was hoping to put these online for members to view and add results as required

The league structure follows the below format with 6 leagues

league 1

```
|        | John | Mark | Peter | Martin | Paul |
|:------:|:----:|:----:|:-----:|:------:|:----:|
| John   | NULL |   3  |   0   |    1   |   2  |
| Mark   |   0  | NULL |   1   |    3   |   0  |
| Peter  |   3  |   3  |  NULL |    1   |   3  |
| Martin |   3  |   1  |   3   |  NULL  |   2  |
| Paul   |   3  |   3  |   0   |    3   | NULL |
```

League 2

etc etc

I have designed the table structure as

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Results](
    [ResultId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LeagueId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Player1Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Player2Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Player1Result] [int] NULL,
    [Player2Result] [int] NULL) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Players](
    [PlayerId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](150) NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Leagues](
    [LeagueId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LeagueName] [nvarchar](50) NULL)
```

I am trying to write a query which gives me the output of each divsion in one query rather than several to give me the output
can anyone help with the query?

what i have so far is

```
select p.FirstName, p1.player2result, p2.player2result, p3.player2result, p4.player2result
from
    (select player2Result from Results p1 where p.playerId = p1.Player2Id
    union
    select player2Result from Results p2 where p.playerId = p2.Player2Id
    union
    select player2Result from Results p3 where p.playerId = p3.Player2Id
    union
    select player2Result from Results p4 where p.playerId = p4.Player2Id) as opResult
LEFT JOIN Players p on opResult.Player2Result = p.PlayerId
GROUP BY p.FirstName, p1.player2result, p2.player2result, p3.player2result, p4.player2result
```

Comment: I guess there is nothing related to mysql. remove the tag please then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example.

This will keep its self up to date as you add new names etc so no need to edit the SQL every time you make a new player..

The only setback is that the players name will need to be unique!!!!

i assume you will be able to adapt this for showing each league but if you need help with this then just ask.

also note my test data is not the same as yours. i just made up random data.

```
  ------------------------------------------
  --Data setup
  ------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Results]
  (
      [ResultId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [LeagueId] [int] NOT NULL,
      [Player1Id] [int] NOT NULL,
      [Player2Id] [int] NOT NULL,
      [Player1Result] [int] NULL,
      [Player2Result] [int] NULL
  )

  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Players]
  (
      [PlayerId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
      [FirstName] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
      [LastName] [nvarchar](150) NULL
  )

  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Leagues]
  (
      [LeagueId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [LeagueName] [nvarchar](50) NULL
  )

  INSERT INTO Players (UserId,FirstName)
  VALUES 
      (1,'John'),
      (2,'Mark'),
      (3,'Peter'),
      (4,'Martin'),
      (5,'Paul')

  INSERT INTO Leagues(LeagueName)
  VALUES
      ('League 1'),
      ('League 2')

  INSERT INTO Results(LeagueId,Player1Id,Player2Id,Player1Result,Player2Result)
  VALUES
      (1,1,2,3,0),
      (1,1,3,0,4),
      (1,1,4,1,2),
      (1,1,5,2,1),
      (1,2,3,1,4),
      (1,2,4,3,2),
      (1,2,5,0,1),
      (1,3,4,1,2),
      (1,3,5,3,1),
      (1,4,5,2,1)

  ------------------------------------------
  --Answer
  ------------------------------------------

  --Get a list of all the names in the system
  DECLARE @Names NVARCHAR(MAX)

  SET @Names = (SELECT '[' + STUFF((SELECT '],[' + FirstName FROM Players ORDER BY FirstName FOR XML PATH('')),1,3,'') + ']')

  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

  --Create the matrix
  SET @SQL = '
  SELECT FirstName1,' + @Names + '
  FROM
  (
      SELECT P1.FirstName AS FirstName1,P2.FirstName AS FirstName2,R.Player1Result AS Result
      FROM  Results AS R
      INNER JOIN Players AS P1 ON P1.PlayerId = R.Player1Id
      INNER JOIN Players AS P2 ON P2.PlayerId = R.Player2Id

      UNION ALL

      SELECT P2.FirstName AS FirstName1,P1.FirstName AS FirstName2,R.Player2Result AS Result
      FROM  Results AS R
      INNER JOIN Players AS P1 ON P1.PlayerId = R.Player1Id
      INNER JOIN Players AS P2 ON P2.PlayerId = R.Player2Id
  ) AS P
  PIVOT
  (
      MAX (Result)
      FOR FirstName2 IN
      ( ' + @Names + ' )
  ) AS pvt
  ORDER BY pvt.FirstName1;
  '

  EXEC(@SQL)

  ------------------------------------------
  --Cleanup
  ------------------------------------------

  DROP TABLE Results
  DROP TABLE Players
  DROP TABLE Leagues
```

Comment: No problem.  I am sure like many others on this page I just love solving problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky because each player can either be player1 or player2 in the Results table.

This approach might work:

```
--First, make a list of each player and their score against their opponent
WITH res (pID, score, opponentID) AS (
  SELECT res.player1id [pID], res.player1Result [score], res.player2id [opponent]
  FROM results res
  UNION
  SELECT res2.player2id [pID], res2.player2Result [score], res2.player1id [opponent]
  FROM results res2
) 

--Then select one row for each player with all of their scores.
SELECT p.FirstName,
  res1.score [1],
  res2.score [2],
  res3.score [3],
  res4.score [4],
  res5.score [5]
FROM Players p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN res res1 ON p.playerid = res1.pID and res1.opponentID = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN res res2 ON p.playerid = res2.pID and res2.opponentID = 2
  LEFT OUTER JOIN res res3 ON p.playerid = res3.pID and res3.opponentID = 3
  LEFT OUTER JOIN res res4 ON p.playerid = res4.pID and res4.opponentID = 4
  LEFT OUTER JOIN res res5 ON p.playerid = res5.pID and res5.opponentID = 5
```

The downside to this approach is that you may need to add or remove code if your leagues have more or fewer players.  If you need it to be dynamic, you could try a dynamic PIVOT, which would add to the complexity.

Comment: I have added a PIVOT answer to this question.